# Building Cordova Android with Java 8 without Jack

Tags: android, cordova, java-8, android-jack-and-jill

Up until now I have been using Java 8 features in my hybrid Cordova Android project - I have one custom plugin where I use Java 8 features such as `try-with-resources`.  In order to do so all I needed to do, apart from ensuring that JDK 8 was installed, was  to create a `platforms/android/build-extras.gradle` file containing the following

```
defaultConfig
{
 jackOptions {enabled true}
}
compileOptions 
{
 sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
allprojects
{
 compileOptions
 {
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
}
```

Having just setup a new chunkier Ubuntu machine to with the latest version of Android Studio - I use the CLI but find that using Android Studio and SDK Manager is the easiest way of ensuring that the Android platforms, tools etc are correctly instatlled - I did the following

- edited `platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js` so it emits distributionURL as `https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`
- edited `platforms/android/build.gradle` so it uses the latest Android Gradle plugin [as specicfied here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle).

  `dependencies 
   {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
   }`
- edited `platforms/android/build-extras.gradle`, [as suggested here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support), to read

  `android 
  {
   compileOptions 
   {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
  }`

At this point I felt that I had done everything necessary to appease both Cordova and Android so I proceeded to issue a `cordova clean` which reported success followed by `cordova build android` which comes back with the following

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. 
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration 
':debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve project :CordovaLib.
Required by:
project :
> Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to
configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project 
:CordovaLib.
```

The stacktrace simply contains this

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/droidos/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Subproject Path: CordovaLib  
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated... .
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete...
WARNING: Configuration 'debugCompile' is obsolete...
WARNING: Configuration 'releaseCompile' is obsolete...
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore....
```

Switching back to the old style `build-extras.gradle` file does not work any more either and comes back with the complaint along the lines of `I don't know Jack`.

I must be missing something here.  What is the right way to compile a Cordova Android project to use Java 8 from the Cordova CLI?  For completeness I should mention that I am working with Node 8.9.2 and Cordova 7.1.0.  Upgrading either beyond that point is causing trouble with the [Duktape Javascript](https://github.com/square/duktape-android) scripting engine I am using in the plugin.